# how to increase the counter by one

Tags: php, mysql, database

I do not understand what is wrong with me, I believe that the request to the correct database.
I am trying to increase the counter by one views, while post_id and hosts simply rewritten or left unchanged

when the user selects a specific post views counter shall be increased by one, and another counter hosts remain unchanged.

```
$current_ip = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."views_date where ip_address='$ip'"));

if($current_ip == '1') {

  $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix."views_count",
    array(              
      'post_id' =>$id,
      'hosts'=>'hosts', 
      'views'=>'views'+1 //not increased by one
    )
  );

}


"post_id INT(11) NOT NULL, hosts INT(11) NOT NULL, views INT(11) NOT NULL"
```

Comment: [`$wpdb->get_row()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) returns whole row data from  your table how can you compare whole row data will be equal to 1 ?

Comment: as it should be? I'm completely confused. Insert function works fine and cant do update (

Comment: I doubt whether this condition is ever satisfied -> if($current_ip == '1') { .. }

Comment: if user has gone to the page just something I need to increase the counter "views" by one. I do not understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `'views'=> views+1`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely failing because `if($current_ip == '1')` will not be equal to 1.

`$current_ip` is the results of the complete row of data from the database, so you need to get the data from the IP column, something like:

```
while($row = $current_ip->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $ip_value_from_database = $row["ip_address"];
}

if($ip_value_from_database == '1') {
    //update query
}
```